# Permission denied (keyboard-interactive) error in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, posh-ssh

using powershell posh-ssh , when i try this
Approach A

`$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential Get-Credential`

i get this error

`New-SSHSession: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).`

when i tried
Approach B

`$cred = Get-Credential`

`$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $cred`

it works!!!! but when i exit the session and open powershell session the error occurs when i try Approach B and it works when i try Approach A!!!!

i went to C:\OpenSSH-Win64\sshd_config_default i commented out
`PasswordAuthentication yes`
and restarted the service but still same, i made sure the sshd demon is running from C:\OpenSSH-Win64\sshd.exe

Comment: It is a fundamental syntax requirement in PowerShell to enclose _commands_ in `(...)` so as to allow them to act as _arguments_ to other commands (e.g. `ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content -Raw file.json)`) and to participate in _expressions_ (e.g. `1 + (Write-Output 42)`). See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: In other words: replace `-Credential Get-Credential` with `-Credential (Get-Credential)`